# TLSv1.2 cipher with a Oracle Java less than 8

Tags: java, ssl

I am confused and want know about , any ways which we can achieve TLSv2 with Oracle java less than 8?

With Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) , will be able to resolve TLSv1.2 cipher with a Oracle Java less than 8?

```
Below oracle sites mentioned about using
```

**TLS** Cipher Suite<>**J2SE v**1.4**   J2SE v**1.4.1**, v**1.4.2** J2SE **5.0**    Java **SE 6**   Java **SE 7**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

```
Blob on Java 7 and TLSv1.2
```

http://fsanglier.blogspot.cz/2015/04/java-7-and-tlsv12-supported-but-not-enabled.html

```
Java 7 introduced support for TLS v1.2 ()
```

BUT does not enable it by default. In other words, your client app must explicitly specify "TLS v1.2" at SSLContext creation, or otherwise will just not be able to use it.

1. MQ version '7.1.0.7'
2. OS->'Linux 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64'

**Java Client uses**
1. jdk1.7.0_21

Comment: Your question contains already the answer: it is not possible without specifically dealing with it on the client side. Are you just asking if this information is really true (it is) or is there another question I did not see?

Comment: yaa , just want to know about above settings and its really work or not. Provide sites URL , i can get some sample code to perform some Testing. Even in  above question **SunProviders.html** , given some TLS ciphers ,  not clear about tables mentioned.

Comment: if local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar from jre8 , copied to jre7 folder , will work? site which can provide Oracle ciper to Algorithms [SHA256withRSA,SHA384withRSA,SHA512withRSA]

Comment: There are lots of posts at stackoverflow.com already dealing with this topic. Please look [there](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+7+tls+1.2+site%3Astackoverflow.com) before asking a new question and then describe what part of the problem is not already answered.

Comment: Most of these sites mentioned about Socket level enabling TLSv2. My question is on JAVA client[jdk7] to MQ[71]